# Using input value in a javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use a value of a hidden input field in my javascript function. I'm kind of a javascript noob, so I don't know how to use it yet. Now I have two seperate javascript codes which I want to combine.

My HTML: `<input type="hidden" id="frequentie_x" value="{$profile.x}"/>`

My first JS code to get the value of the id frequentie_x:

```
 <script> 

    function frequentie() { 
         window.frequentie =  
            document.getElementById("frequentie_x").value; 
    }
</script>
```

And my second JS code which I need for displaying the correct radiobutton on my page:

```
<script>

    $(function () { $('input[value="(Here goes the value of input field hidden"]').filter(':visible:first').prop('checked', true)} ); 

</script>
```

Does anyone know how to combine these two into one script to use the value of my hidden input value in the second script? Or maybe an easier way to do this of course.

***Edit:***

I tested the following code and it works to show the variable input value that is loaded from a database to show in the p element with id result:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() { 
        var frequentie =  document.getElementById("frequentie").value;
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = frequentie; 
          }
 $(function () { $('input[value="Dagelijks"]').filter(':visible:first').prop('checked', true)} );
</script> 

  <p id="result"></p>
```

Now all I need is to use the var frequentie in this part: $('input[value="Dagelijks"]'). Does anyone know how to use the var frequentie from funtion myFunction() here?

Comment: You probably cannot use it that way in a jQuery selector, because changes to the value don't reflect to the attribute (which serves only as an initial value).

Comment: The value of the hidden input field is loaded server side before the page is loaded and doesn't change. I think it is possible then?

Comment: if the value is not dynamically changed, why not generate it on the server side along with the rest of HTML?

Comment: The problem is we use software where we don't have acces to this. So it's a big big workaround... ( it is dynamically changed based on the profile's ID, but not anymore when it's already generated as value in the html ).  If I could it would be much easier